# Adding C++ library to CLion Project

Tags: c++, c++14

I am new to C++ and am facing alot of issues when trying to use pre-existing libraries in my CLion project. Would like to know how to add libarries like https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp to my CLion project so that I can use it. I am facing issues such as errors that boost is not found and stuff like that. Would appreciate if someone is able to explain how adding of library in CLion works.

Comment: I am getting the error 
"CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)" on CLion

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But try downloading it and adding it to the same file directory of your Clion project. And after that, you can include that library via

```
#include "restc-cpp/restc-cpp.h"
```

Scroll down at the GitHub page. It tells you how to include the library